# NIntegrate gives $0$ for a positive integrand

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, numerics

I have a positive function called "integrand" and I want to perform numerical integration. The following code creates the function "integrand" and performs the numerical integration:

```
NN = 300; n = 30; M = 5;
k = a*(M + 1)^2/NN;
ei[l_] := 1 + 2*k*Cos[Pi*l/(M + 1)] - 2*k;
prod = 1;
For[l = 1, l <= M, l++,
  prod = prod*ei[l];
  ];
dA = Simplify[prod];
R = ConstantArray[0, {M, M}];
For[jj = 1, jj <= M, jj++,
For[l = 1, l <= M, l++,
    R[[jj, l]] = Sin[l*Pi*jj/(M + 1)];
    ];
  ];
Q = Simplify[Sqrt[2/(M + 1)]*R];
Dinvn = ConstantArray[0, {M, M}];
For[l = 1, l <= M, l++,
  Dinvn[[l, l]] = 1/ei[l]^n;
  ];
Ainvn = Q.Dinvn.Transpose[Q];
dAi = 1/dA^n;
f[x_] := PDF[
   ProductDistribution[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   NormalDistribution[0, 1], NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   NormalDistribution[0, 1], NormalDistribution[0, 1]], x];
w = {x[1], x[2], v, x[4], x[5]};
integrand = f[Ainvn.w]*dAi;
NIntegrate[integrand /. v -> 1,
 {x[1], -∞, ∞},{x[2],-∞,∞}, {x[4], -∞, ∞}, {x[5],-∞, ∞}, {a, 1, 2}]
```

The output:

```
NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option.

0.
```

We can analyze "integrand" by doing some examples:

```
dAi /. a -> 1.4

2.06591*10^30

Ainvn.w /. {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1, x[4] -> 1, x[5] -> 1, a -> 1.5, v -> -0.5}

{-6.71576*10^13, 1.1632*10^14, -1.34315*10^14, 1.1632*10^14, -6.71576*10^13}
```

Notice that $f$ is the joint density of five independent $\text{Normal}(0,1)$ distributions. Anyway, the thing is that $f(\{10^{13},10^{13},10^{13},10^{13},10^{13}\})\approx 0$, but not exactly zero. Mathematica gives underflow. The result of the evaluation of $f$ should be a number very close to $0$, that with dAi should compensate. Or maybe it is a problem of the integration performed by NIntegrate. How can I modify my code so that the result obtained by NIntegrate is correct?

Comment: @bills yes, it has. I have increased the `AccuracyGoal`, `WorkingPrecission` and it returns a very small number `-3.49697474357660*10^-221213430006`. I also work with double precision `NN=300` and `n=30` and with `Method -> "MultidimensionalRule", AccuracyGoal -> 10, \
WorkingPrecision -> 15`. I do not know how reliable (and useful) is this result.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Do you mean to put Method -> "MultidimensionalRule", AccuracyGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 15 in NIntegrate? What do you mean by double precision in NN=300 and n=30?

Comment: You should evaluate `integrand`, not the pieces.  That's the way to find out the problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 If I evaluate integrand, I obtain underflow. I do not know how to solve that.

Comment: Oh, yes to the first question, and `NN=300.` and `n=30.`. I noted that working with the integers, the integral returns `0` without warnings or errors.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas It is true that now I do not obtain zero everywhere. But the result is not reliable. In fact, I know from a mathematical proof that, adding an integration with respect to $v$, the result should be exactly $1$. But `res = NIntegrate[integrand, {v,-Infinity,Infinity}, {x[1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x[2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x[4], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {x[5], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {alpha, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, Method -> "MultidimensionalRule", AccuracyGoal -> 30, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 50]` gives `10^-1264876713`.

Comment: It means your problem in not well scaled for machine precision.  The values computed, including intermediate ones, that are to be treated as nonzero should fit comfortably between the magnitudes 10^±308.  The culprit is the argument to `Exp` in `integrand`.  Haven't thought of a fix yet.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your comment. So, should I divide by $10^{\text{something}}$ at some steps? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more accurate, since the integrand underflows outside the region:

```
NIntegrate[
 integrand /. v -> 1,
 {x[1], -2, -1, 0}, {x[2], -1, 0, 1}, {x[4], -1, 0, 1}, {x[5], -2, -1, 0}, {a, 1.8, 1.9, 2},
 MinRecursion -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 4]
(*  1.4796*10^41  *)
```

*Original answer:*

This gives a positive result:

```
NIntegrate[
 integrand /. v -> 1,
 {x[1], -∞, -1, ∞}, {x[2], -∞, 0, ∞}, {x[4], -∞, 0, ∞}, {x[5], -∞, -1, ∞}, {a, 1, 1.9, 2},
 MinRecursion -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 4]
(*  5.22114*10^43  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

For efficiency and brevity of code, recommend that you avoid use of [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) constructs, e.g.,

```
NN = 300; n = 30; M = 5;
k = a*(M + 1)^2/NN;
ei[l_] := 1 + 2*k*Cos[Pi*l/(M + 1)] - 2*k;

dA = Times @@ ei@Range[M] // Simplify;

R = Array[Sin[#1*#2*Pi/(M + 1)] &, {M, M}];

Q = Sqrt[2/(M + 1)]*R;

Dinvn = DiagonalMatrix[1/(ei@Range[M])^n];
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not know much about Mathematica. Your comment has been very interesting.